# How to get all products from woo-commerce?

Tags: wordpress, rest, woocommerce, product, woocommerce-rest-api

I have setup Woo-Commerce which have more than 1000 products. Using Woocommerce rest api php library I am trying to get all products.

But it gives me 10 products. If I use filter[limit] it gives me around 400 products not more than this.

```
$res = $wc_api->get_products(array( 'filter[limit]' => 400 ) );
```

Can anyone say me how can I get all products from woocommerce?

Answer (score 1):

For the latest version of the WC API, use

```
$products = $client->products->get( '', ['filter[limit]' => -1] );
```

If it's not working try replacing the limit with posts_per_page as follows:

```
'filter[posts_per_page]'=>-1
```

Depending on your server specs and the total number of products this type of query might need a lot of memory so if you get any error or the query doesn't finish be sure that the memory limit in php.ini is high enough.

Comment: I have just tried this but got an error "Invalid JSON returned for http://www.**********.***/wc-api/v2/products?filter%5Blimit%5D=-1&oauth_consumer_key=________"

Comment: Is there any other solution?

Comment: When I used $res = $wc_api->get_products(array('filter[limit]' => -1) ); but it gives error message"Invalid nonce - nonce has already been used".

Comment: You could try this instead: $this->client->products->get(null, array('filter[limit]' => -1));

Answer (score 1):

This isn't the latest API endpoint:

```
/wc-api/v3/products?filter[limit]=
```

You have to fetch page per page to get all the products:

```
$page = 1;
$products = [];
$all_products = [];
do{
  try {
    $products = $wc->get('products',array('per_page' => 100, 'page' => $page));
  }catch(HttpClientException $e){
    die("Can't get products: $e");
  }
  $all_products = array_merge($all_products,$products);
  $page++;
} while (count($products) > 0);
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51555088/9802294)

Answer (score 0):

http://localhost:8888/wp-json/wc/store/products

Try this endpoint for list products. You can get Categories and Prices as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a Laravel package like `codexshaper/laravel-woocommerce` or `corcel/woocommerce` or some other package, be careful with the product type in your WooCommerce website. By default when you call `$products = Product::all();` it just gives you the products with `simple` product-type.

This is the list of default product-type in woocommece:

```
'simple', 'grouped', 'external', 'variable', 'external', 'subscription', 'variable-subscription'
```

So You have to specify the product-type of you want to get other products.

```
$product = WooProduct::all(['per_page'=> '100','type'=>'simple']);
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found is iterating over all pages (1st, 2nd, etc...) of products using the below `wp-cli` command until the returned list is empty.

`wp wc product list --page={page} --format=json --fields=id,description`

It mimics the way we work in wp admin.