# How to get products from all vendors

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I’m using this API to get all products:
    wp-json/wc/v3/products?per_page=100&category=15

It only takes products that belong to the vendor that is logged. How can i get all products from all vendors?

Answer (score 0):

Using -1 limit should give you all products from all vendors:

```
wp-json/wc/v3/products?filter[limit] =-1
```

Comment: You can find information here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48476534/get-all-products-from-woocommerce-using-rest-api

Comment: It still  takes only  products that belong to the vendor that is logged.

Comment: Try checking if you can get products from other vendor and see if you have any errors: `/wp-json/wc/v3/products?per_page=100&category=15&vendor=vendor_id` : replace vendor_id with any of the other logged out vendors

Comment: I still have the same result, product that belong logged user

Comment: I don't know why this works with: /wp-json/wc/v1/products?per_page=100&category=15

Comment: `/wp-json/wc/v3/products?per_page=100&category=15&include_vendor=[vendor_id1, vendor_id2,...]` - apparently you can include the list of vendor ids you want product from using the attribute `include_vendor`.